# Reading source files in MSVS project using xmlstarlet

Tags: attributes, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet, vcxproj

I am trying to get the source files and include directories from a vcxproj file. Eg of vcsproj:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
.... 
 <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="$(SrcDir)d1\f1cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="$(SrcDir)d2\f2.cpp" />
 </ItemGroup>
...
</Project>
```

I tried this:
 `xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//_:ItemGroup/ClCompile/@Include" myProj.vcxproj` but didn't work.

However, when I tried this (copying the code from some page that I came across), it works:

```
 echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <ELEMENT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <SUB_ELEMENT attribute="attr_value"/>
</ELEMENT>' | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//_:SUB_ELEMENT/@attribute' --nl
o/p: attr_value
```

I don't see how the two are different with respect to reading an attribute value from an xml with a namespace. I further tried a stripped down version of the vcxproj file:

```
 echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="$(SrcDir)d1\f1cpp" /> </ItemGroup> </Project>' | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//_:ItemGroup/@Include' --nl
o/p: <no o/p>
```

Any indication on why it is not working or how to get this to work would be very helpful.

Edit: Expected output from the vcxproj would be a list of filenames. For the above command it would be `$(SrcDir)d1\f1cpp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any indication on why it is not working or how to get this to work would be very helpful

Since you're using the default namespace add the [`_:`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05.html)
shortcut on the node test in each
[location step](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#section-Location-Steps),
and the [`-T (--text)`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04.html#idm47989546279904)
option to make text mode output:

```sh
xmlstarlet select -T -t -v "//_:ItemGroup/_:ClCompile/@Include" -n file.xml
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks and lot! This is interesting and not really clear from the xmlstartlet help pages.